# Downloading a file from MinIO S3 storage in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, amazon-s3, minio

I am trying to download a file from minio using official Minio package.

The way I managed to download a file seems pretty incorrect to me:

```
var downloadStream = new MemoryStream();
var args = new GetObjectArgs()
            .WithBucket(bucketName)
            .WithObject(fileName)
            .WithCallbackStream(x =>
            {
                x.CopyTo(downloadStream);
                downloadStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            });
```

I see 2 problems in here:

- I am loading the whole file into memory (can cause memory overflow if many users are trying to download or files are too big)
- The copying might take a considerable amount of time

Also the naive assignation `downloadStream = x` does not work as the callback stream gets closed and disposed after the callback body ends its execution.

I think I also need to mention that I cannot directly write this stream to the request output because I am using minio in the different assembly isolated from ASP.NET controller.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a little wrapper that forwards the stream from Minio client without copying the whole file into memory.

Usage (the service):

```
var statArgs = new StatObjectArgs()
    .WithObject(name)
    .WithBucket(_bucketName);
var stat = await _minio.StatObjectAsync(statArgs, token);

var res = new ReleaseableFileStreamModel
{
    ContentType = stat.ContentType,
    FileName = name,
};

// the magic begins here
var getArgs = new GetObjectArgs()
    .WithObject(name)
    .WithBucket(_bucketName)
    .WithCallbackStream(res.SetStreamAsync);

await res.HandleAsync(_minio.GetObjectAsync(getArgs, token));
// the magic partially ends here

return res;
```

Controller action:

```
public async Task DownloadAsync(
    [FromBody] DownloadFileRequest request,
    CancellationToken token)
{
    using var res = await _service.DownloadAsync(request, token);
    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
    Response.ContentType = res.ContentType;
    await res.Stream.CopyToAsync(Response.Body, token);
    // the magic finally ends here when res is disposed
}
```

And the magic wrapper itself:

```
public class ReleaseableFileStreamModel : IDisposable
{
    private readonly TaskCompletionSource _setStreamTaskCompletionSource = new();
    private readonly TaskCompletionSource _releaseTaskCompletionSource = new();

    private bool _set;
    private bool _disposedValue;

    public string FileName { get; init; } = null!;

    public string ContentType { get; init; } = null!;

    public Stream Stream { get; set; } = null!;

    /// <summary>
    /// Set <see cref="Stream"/>
    /// and return <see cref="Task"/> for awaiting of the Stream usage finish
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stream"></param>
    /// <param name="token"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Task SetStreamAsync(Stream stream, CancellationToken token)
    {
        if (Stream != null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Stream is already set.");
        }

        _set = true;
        Stream = stream;
        _setStreamTaskCompletionSource.SetResult();
        return _releaseTaskCompletionSource.Task;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set <see cref="Stream"/>
    /// and return <see cref="Task"/> for awaiting of the Stream usage finish
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stream"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Task SetStreamAsync(Stream stream)
        => SetStreamAsync(stream, CancellationToken.None);

    /// <summary>
    /// Release <see cref="Stream"/>
    /// </summary>
    public void Release()
    {
        _releaseTaskCompletionSource.SetResult();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Process <paramref name="task"/>, that sets <see cref="Stream"/>,
    /// and return <see cref="Task"/> that awaits setting of <see cref="Stream"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="task"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Task HandleAsync<T>(Task<T> task)
    {
        task.ContinueWith(
            HandleFail<T>(),
            CancellationToken.None,
            TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent,
            TaskScheduler.Current);

        return StreamSetTask;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(disposing: true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                Release();
            }

            _disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// <see cref="Task"/> that awaits setting of <see cref="Stream"/>
    /// </summary>
    private Task StreamSetTask => _setStreamTaskCompletionSource.Task;

    private Action<Task<T>> HandleFail<T>()
        => t
            =>
            {
                var ex = t.Exception;
                if (ex != null)
                {
                    _setStreamTaskCompletionSource.TrySetException(ex);
                    _releaseTaskCompletionSource.TrySetException(ex);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!_set)
                    {
                        _setStreamTaskCompletionSource.TrySetException(new OperationCanceledException());
                    }

                    _releaseTaskCompletionSource.TrySetResult();
                }
            };
}
```

Comment: ASP.NET controllers should return the file via `return File(stream, mimeType)`. What is your endpoint returning actually? And what does the client code look like?

Comment: Why are you saying you are not copying the entire file into memory since you're doing `await res.Stream.CopyToAsync(Response.Body);`? This call is actually copying the entire file into the response body in the memory of the server **before** the response is being returned to the client calling the endpoint.

Comment: Returning a `Stream` object from the controller via `return File(stream, mimeType);` allows for the client to start reading from the response stream client-side which would then start reading from the MinIO backend storage via the intermediate `Stream` they should have provided.

Comment: Additionally, you don't need to make an additional call to `StatObject`. The `GetObject` call already returns the `ObjectStat` which you can use in order to obtain the content type.

Comment: @Ceco 
> _Why are you saying you are not copying the entire file into memory..._

Because `Response.Body` is `HttpResponseStream`, but not `MemoryStream`, feel free to compare their implementations.

Comment: @Ceco > _ASP.NET controllers should return the file via `return File(stream, mimeType)`_ 

It isn't the only possible way. Furthermore, it can't be used in such case.

Comment: @Ceco > _The `GetObject` call already returns the `ObjectStat` which you can use in order to obtain the content type._

Yes, I know. But not that easy as you suggested. You are welcome to modify my implementation to avoid second call to S3.